# python equivalent for curl --interface

Tags: python, linux, shell, centos

What is the python equivalent for following shell command:
curl --interface 10.91.56.2 http:/10.91.55.3/file0.txt
????

I am using CentOS6.5-Linux and I want to send http request from virtual IP addresses like eth0:0,eth0:1,eth0:2,etc simultaneously with eth0. I am actually trying to make one traffic generator tool using python. I have been successful in sending multiple and concurrent http requests and now my next step is to send such requests from multiple ip addresses.I used following cURL command to send request from eth0:1 " curl--interface 10.91.56.2 http:/10.91.55.3/file0.txt" and I was successful in generating traffic from virtual eth0:1. Can anyone guide me how to do this using python? 10.91.56.2 is my virtual eth0:1 IP interface and 10.91.55.3 is my server address... –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, eth0's ip is 10.91.56.3 and eth0:1's ip is 10.91.56.4 so, to generate traffic using 10.91.56.4(eth0:1)

Followed answer by @AKX here

In above answer in 3rd class write your interface's ip instead of 127.0.0.1 eg in my case i did like this:

```
class BindableHTTPHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def http_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(BindableHTTPConnectionFactory('10.91.56.4'), req)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python Urllib2 provides perfect platform for making any HTTP request. In your case you can use urlopen() function...

More about this libary can be found in the below link:

[how-to-use-urllib2-in-python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/how-to-use-urllib2-in-python/)

Comment: but urlopen wont allow me to use virtual interface to send http request right?